# Drawing a shape with an undefined size

Tags: java

I have been looking at the Java2D tutorials and was wondering how to draw a shape using the mouse to define its size(i.e the size of the shape is not fixed). I haven't come across a tutorial specifically for this and was wondering how I could implement this for a rectangle for example.

Comment: Did you try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the size is FIXED at every moment. When you add a `MouseMotionListener`, before the next event is captured, you can paint the shape on the screen with the size depending on current `MouseEvent.getPoint()` which tells you the coordinates of your mouse location.

Override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of the component. and call `repaint()` method after each update of the mouse location and the size of the shape:

```
class YourPanel extends JPanel extends MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

    private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();

    public YourPanel () {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.draw(rect);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent me) {
        rect.setSize(me.getX() - rect.x, me.getY() - rect.y);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {
        rect.setLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
        repaint();
    }

    // Other methods...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shapes is a word and java class  that represents differnet geometric figures like rectangles, ellipses, poly lines, etc.

So first the user would have to decide which shape, e.g a poly line.
You then would catch mouse left click events, and for each click read the mouse coordinates and add that coordinate pair (e.g java.awt.geom.Point2D()) to an `ArrayList<Point2D>`.
The size of such an list is (practically) unbounded.
 On each click you will create a current shaped object that will be drawn. Once the user clicks right mouse, the shape is ready und you store it in list of shapes.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your class implement a mouse listener, then save the variables of the mouse listener with getX and getY to draw the shape.